# R get row number of the first row that has a string variable in a data frame column

Tags: r, string

I am working with data frames that are dynamically generated.

```
structure(list(`4` = c(NA, NA, "Location", NA), `5` = c(NA, NA, 
"Size", "W")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The above looks like this:

```
                                      4    5
1                                  <NA> <NA>
2                                  <NA> <NA>
3                              Location Size
4                                  <NA>    W
```

From each column in the data frame I want to get the first character variable.  For example from the above table, I want to retrieve Location and Size and use them as my column header.

Since the tables are dynamically generated, I am not sure in which line the string variable would appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to loop through the columns, get the first non-NA element with `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  summarise_all(funs(.[!is.na(.)][1]))
```

---

Or with `sapply`, use the same logic

```
sapply(df1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
```

Or with `which` on logical matrix (`!is.na(df1)`), subset the data, get the first element of each column by filtering out the duplicate column index

```
ind <- which(!is.na(df1), arr.ind = TRUE)
df1[ind][!duplicated(ind[,2])]
#[1] "Location" "Size"
```

Comment: So you've got the value (the content of the cell), but how to get the row number, please)

Comment: @dpelisek If you check the last option.  the 'ind' gives row/column as a matrix.  From that you can extract the row index